# Magento - Check if subcategory exists in current category

Tags: magento, categories

I have the following category setup in my  magento store:

```
store root
|
bedroom    kitchen     bathroom    
|            |            |            
furniture  furniture   furniture         
lighting   lighting    misc
misc
```

I need to be able to check if the category `misc` exists as a subcategory in my current category or not, and if so show a particular block.

So if i was in the kitchen category it would not show but in bedroom and bathroom it would.

How can i do this this check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your sub-category `misc`

```
$currentCategoryId = 10; 
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //only active categories
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $currentCategoryId)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', 'misc');
```

To check if your collection contains at least 1 record in it:

```
if ($collection->getSize() > = 1) {
    //'misc' sub-category exists
}
else {
    //'misc' sub-category does not exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Load you current category using and get its Id

```
$currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
$currentCatId = $currentCat->getId();
```

Load the 'misc' sub-category using

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', 'misc');
$_categoryParentId = $_category->getParentCategory()->getId();

if( $currentCatId == $_categoryParentId){
//Do your stuffs
}
```

Though you have two categories with the same name misc, so you would want to laod category by url-key or parse through the multiple category array to test.

Answer (score 0):

Try flollowing,

```
<?php  
$categoryId = 5;
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getChildren();
$catAsArray = explode(',', $categories);
//you can have $catAsArray to check if it has subcategories
foreach($catAsArray as $child)
{
    $_child = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $child );
    echo $_child->getName() . '<br />';
    echo $_child->getUrl() . '<br />';
    echo $_child->getDescription() . '<br />';
}
?>
```

Or the other way,

```
<?php

$categoryId = 5;
$_category  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

if($_category->hasChildren())
{


}
?>
```